# Angular 2 - How to pass URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I have created a single page mortgage calculator application in Angular 2, which acts like a learning playground for me (trying to get more accustomed to technology stack currently used at work)... It's running at http://www.mortgagecalculator123.com if you want to look at it. I've made it open source with a Fork Me link right on the page if you want to look at it.

Anyhow, what I want to do, is to be able to pass variables to my app, straight from the URL, so they can be consumed by my Angular 2 app. Something like this: http://www.mortgagecalculator123.com/?var1=ABC&var2=DEF

I've tried following, in my app.component.ts, I've added following:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

AppComponent {
private var1: string;
private var2: string;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.var1 = params['var1'];
      this.var2 = params['var2'];
  });

  console.log(this.var1, this.var2);
}
...
}
```

But this won't work, when I run **npm start**, I get following error:

> aot/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts(45,30): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I created a pull request with the query params working. I will try to explain everything I did.

The reason why the previous answers doesn't work is because you aren't using the router at all. You created a massive app component without routes. To fix that we need to start using the route module, I also advise you to read these two tutorials: [Routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) and [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

First we need to change your `index.html`, add this to your `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

See [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) why it's important to add that.

Then since you are using your `AppComponent` to show everything we need to create a new component, which we will call `RootComponent`. On your `index.html` change `<my-app>` to `<root>`; it will look like this:

```
<root>Loading...</root>
```

Now inside your `app` folder we need to create two files the first one will be `root.component.ts` which will look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class RootComponent {
  constructor() {  }
}
```

Look that we have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as a template, Angular will inject our components based on the route.

We still need to create one more file, which will be `main.route.ts`, this is what it looks like:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent }
];
export const mainRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes);
```

In this file we are saying that for our base route, we want to render our `AppComponent`

We have created our new files, now we need to tell our **App Module** about them, in your `app.module.ts` so we import the new files and  declare the new component. We also need to change our boostrap component:

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {AppComponent}  from './app.component';
import {RootComponent}  from './root.component'; // we import our new RootComponent
import {ChartModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {TooltipModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { routing, mainRoutingProviders } from './main.routes'; // We also import our Routes

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule,
    FormsModule,
    mainRoutingProviders, // we also need to import our route provider into the module
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing, // and also import our routes declarations
    TooltipModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, RootComponent], // we declare our new RootCpmponent
  bootstrap: [RootComponent] // Notice that we are now using our RootComponent to bootstrap our app
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now with all this in place we can now finally start passing parameters to our app, on your `AppComponent` import the `Router`, `ActivatedRoute` and the `Params` from `@angular/router` so your `AppComponent` will look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private var1: string;
  private var2: string;
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // assign the subscription to a variable so we can unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks
    this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.var1 = params['var1'];
      this.var2 = params['var2'];
      console.log(this.var1, this.var2);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
...
}
```

You can see the pull request [here](https://github.com/JozefJarosciak/MortgageCalculatorAngular2/commit/4b4b6ad846ac378f6ed1142acf0f06550bf37047)

Comment: Fabio, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out the entire time. Thank you so much. I am still a newbie when it comes to Angular 2, so thanks a lot for spending your valuable time to explain everything. Not only it works now, but it has been a great learning exercise following the logic you've outlined. Well deserved 50 points for reputation.

Comment: One more question.... in app.component.ts, is there a need to keep:     'private router: Router', on line 65? Looks like that's an unused parameter no?

Comment: true, you don't need that. Unless you eventually plan to redirect to some route.

Comment: Very good. One thing to add: when using subscribe, remember to implement OnDestroy and unsubscribe on the ngOnDestroy. See the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) section on Angular2 documentation.

Comment: @jjokela True! totally forgot that, going to edit my question

Comment: Im using this inside a service, can I still unsubscribe and how ?

Comment: @STEEL You could create a method on your service to unsubscribe and on your components you can destroy the subscription, by calling that method. But remember if you destroy it, then you need to subscribe again. It really depends on how your application is, maybe doesn't make any sense to destroy it

Comment: This was very useful. I have just one question : for me this works with useHash: false. for useHash: true, when I try https://localhost:4200/?utm_source=letter&utm_medium=email, it redirects to https://localhost:4200/#index.

Comment: I am having same issue ..I tried above solution and no luck .. only difference is I am using redirect in the route  redirectTo:'landing' ,  How to read url paramters in this case ..?

Comment: I have some issues with applying this recipe. What I see on the console of the browser is `NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/?myVar=AAA", urlAfterRedirects: "/searchrecid"}` - the query params though is just an empty object. Could you pls advise? Thanks

Comment: @Picci create a new question with your example, feel free to tag me in the comment, it will be easier to help you ;)

Comment: Solved, thanks. The problem was that I was defining a Route with `path: ''` redirecting to my component which has path `mycomponent`. If I launch `http:\\myapp\?myVar=AAA` I do not get any variable. But if I launch `http:\\myapp\mycomponent?myVar=AAA` I am able to retrieve the parameter from the url.

Comment: This was very helpful. Note that Angular discourages the use of `queryParams`, you should use `queryParamMap` instead. You can access the parameters with `params['params']['var1']` https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are dealing with **Queryparams** . So to access them, you can try below code,

```
this.var1= this.route
      .queryParams
      .map(params => params['var1']);
```

Comment: When I do that, I get following errors:

aot/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts(45,30): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

app/app.component.ts(90,39): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<{ [key: string]: any; }>'.

Comment: I've tried to use: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; but then I am back to original error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. Crazy how something simple as passing vars can be so complicated...

Comment: Thanks for trying, hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: FYI, `queryParams` has been replaced w/ `queryParamsMap`.  [Source](https://angular.io/guide/router)