# How to get router params from url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I get url:

```js
router.events.subscribe(x => {
   if (x instanceof NavigationStart) {
      let url = x.url;
   }
}
```

Continue I need get params from url.

This code in the application root. It need for trace route changes.

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - How to pass URL parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters)

Comment: @FabioAntunes no, ActivatedRoute params is empty

Comment: Then you need to add more code if you want some help, add your routes and component code.

Comment: Please post the route configuration and the info which component contains above code.

Comment: @Zverit, are you using a rootprovider or stateprovider?

Comment: @chiragpatel I don't use angularjs, I use Angular2, there not have stateprovider and rootprovider. If I understand you right.

Comment: Have you considered logging from components being initlized on route change rather than Root comp