# How to read url of browser in angular2 application, and use those parameters in application

Tags: angular, typescript

Ex. i have url in browser i.e http://localhost:2000/#/?userName=john

I want to access the url in appliaction and like to use userName data in application.

I am using angular2 with typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - How to pass URL parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
this.foo = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['userName']
```

to access the value, but you have to set up `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `RouterStateSnapshot`.

Read more about `queryParams` and how to set this up at [the official documentation at Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#query-parameters).