# Read URL (matrix || query) parameters in Angular (2) bootstrapped component

Tags: angular

I would like to read optional URL parameters, no matter query or matrix parameters, in the component bootstrapped by Angular, this while/in ngOnInit().

As far as I understood, "ActivatedRoute" is not available in a component
not loaded in outlet, so with an index.html like:

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

and app.module.ts file containing:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

if, and how, would it be possible to access a parameter from i.e. http://localhost:4200/my-component/id;param1=abc
?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    ... ?
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ... ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private var1: string;
  private var2: string;
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // assign the subscription to a variable so we can unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks
    this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.var1 = params['var1'];
      this.var2 = params['var2'];
    });

    console.log(this.var1, this.var2);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With regard to [Angular 2 - How to pass URL parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters) the provided solution did not work for my origin issue, but [Angular Route guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) is the right feature to have a look.

Via route guards you can intercept and capture route information in front of the component processing.