# Angular-cli: how to run the app from index-dev.html instead of index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used angular-cli (version 1.0.2) to create an angular project, but I need to run from index-dev.html instead of index.html, and index-dev.html will have the same content as index.html, just naming file differently.

Without using angular-cli, I can config lite-server in bs-config.json file. But how can I config in angular-cli project?

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1. Go to .angular-cli.json file
2. Under "apps" section find the property "index"
3. Change the value of this property to "index-dev.html" from "index.html"

Answer (score 1):

Update angular-cli file.

```
{

  "apps": [
    {

      "index": "index-dev.html",
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonnysai but it doesn't work. Here is the error `Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'project-name/src/index-dev.html' in 'project-name':`

Comment: Error showing that Cli was unable find index-dev.html inside src folder. is your index-dev.html included in src folder ?  if its present try run ng serve once again

Comment: my bad, I have accidentally created two index.html and renamed the wrong one.

Comment: Will it be the same case if I want to add parameter after index-dev.html, for example, change to index-dev.html?debug=true in .angular-cli.json? If I made this change, it give me 404 error in debug tool network tab when fetching package.json.

Comment: I dont know whether we can do like that. but you can try with route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters