# Pass query string from index.html to Angular2 component

Tags: angular2-routing

I need some help in accessing query string from index.html in Angular2 component. I have followed this link but it did not work for me
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters)

my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- css importd -->
</head>
<body> 
   <app-root>Loading .. </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
...
public constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivateRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.activateRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params:Params) => {
      console.log(params['code']);
  });
}
```

And I am invoking url   http://localhost:8080/?code=test

Comment: I did not follow you .. how can I set query parameters in template ..? they are coming url. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I want to see your HTML code that passes queryparams

Comment: Updated HTML code . its very simple file

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Nuthan, Is it resolved for you?

Comment: No , I am using local storage to pass data to agnular components

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // get param
    let paramcode = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["code"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
this.activateRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>
 console.log(queryParams['code']);
);
```

Add your html is code :-

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: no luck, i changed template to use <router-outlet></router-outlet>