# Angular 4 application with default page and parameters in url

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe, angular-router

I need to create a web portal that will be embedded inside an iFrame.

Here is the code I use to bootstrap the portal

**Routes configuration**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/dashboard',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'userinformation',
      component: UserInformationComponent
    }
];
```

**Simplified index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <frontend-root></frontend-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**The AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'frontend-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

**The 'app' component html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Portal Main Menu</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="background-color: greenyellow">
      <left-menu></left-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10"  style="background-color: yellow">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the app.component.html file contains the 'router-outlet' where my 'dashboard' and/or my 'userinformations' will be rendered.

Everything works fine, except that the launching application that owns the iframe will send parameters to my webpage thanks to a URL like this one:

```
http://myportal.com/?language=fr&userId=12345
```

And I would like to retrieve these parameters from my AppComponent which is the bootstrapped component.

I tried to use the following solution to retrieve query parameters
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915434/1636492

But as I have a 'default' webpage and a router-outlet not located at the root of my html page, this is not working.

Here are the problems I encountered:

- I can't use component and redirectTo at the same time in a route
  definition (to I used a route.redirect into my OnInit in the
  AppComponent)
- In the root example, the author put the  tag.  But when included in my application, the router-outlet cannot be located there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I found the solution for my app thanks to this link
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157

In the AppComponent, I use this function:

```
function getParameterByName(name: any) {
    const url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[[]]/g, '\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'), results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!results[2]) {
        return '';
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace('/+/g', ' '));
}
```

And in the ngOnInit of the AppComponent, you can retrieve all needed parameters:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let value1 = getParameterByName('value1');
  let value2 = getParameterByName('value2') || ''; // not mandatory
  // do something with value1 & value 2  
}
```