# Angular 4 not displaying data

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display some data from my component to the html. What confuses me is the fact that in older component files this worked. Now, in a few new ones I've created, **it only starts working after logging in and refreshing the page**.

My component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js';

declare let jQuery: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: '../../templates/plan/general-info.html',
})
export class GeneralInfoComponent {

  data;
  selectedCompany = null;
  selectedPlace = null;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.data = this.route.parent.snapshot.data;
    this.selectedCompany = this.data.companies[0];
    this.selectedPlace = this.dataService.selectedPlace.getValue();
  }
}
```

The troubling part of my template file:

```
<div class="general-data">
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.name}}</h3>
  <h3>Reg nr {{selectedCompany.regCode}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.address}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.phone}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.email}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.contactPerson}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedCompany.personCode}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="general-data">
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.name}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.address}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.contactPerson}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.phone}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.email}}</h3>
  <h3>{{selectedPlace.personCode}}</h3>
</div>
```

I don't want to write another hack to display the data with jQuery. The weird part is that the data is nicely displayed after refreshing as if it didn't get the data the first time I load the page. Is something like that even possible?

**NOTE: When logging the data right after giving values to this.selectedCompany and this.selectedPlace, it displays correct info in console.**

**My question: how to get it working straight away without having to refresh the page?**

I've been messing with this the whole day and would love a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the things are not working? did you put a break point and checked?

Comment: you should post your `Resolve` service, which resolves the companies. And please don't  use jQuery. You will get lost too quickly if you use jQuery and angular together :)

Comment: No error in the console when you load the page the first time?

Comment: I 100% get the data, so it seems to me that the problem lies in displaying it. Even if I get the data 0.01s later, it shouldn't affect the displaying since I'm sort of binding the innerHTML's of the h3 tags to the objects from component.ts file. Or should it? @ConnorsFan - no error.

Comment: where is the `data` member of the route parent set? what is your router configuration? Debug an check if `this.route.parent.data` is defined.

Comment: Just reviewed everything for the 100th time and realized, that at the moment the template is rendered, "data" is not defined yet. How to avoid it?
Sorry for giving false information before.

Answer (score 0):

Use "?." (The safe navigation operator) after the object in all expressions.  Like below.

```
{{selectedCompany?.name}}
```

Link - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators

Comment: @Kert, remove the initialization to "null" and check please.
And try to initialize data on "ngOnInit" life cycle hook.

Comment: @Kert, hope this link also helps 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915434/7458082](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915434/7458082)

Comment: When removing the "null" initialization, it worked for a few times but now it's not working again (how???). "ngOnInit" produces this: "TSLint: Implement lifecycle hook interface OnInit for method ngOnInit in class GeneralInfoComponent"

Comment: You should use somethings like this.
`export class GeneralInfoComponent implements OnInit`

link - [https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Comment: Sadly this also doesn't help.