# Can I change the way routing works to include the index.html?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Usually I would route my Angular apps as per usual like:

```
{siteroot}/admin/users/1023929
```

However for my current project I really need to be able to serve the routes from and including the index.html, something like below:

```
{siteroot}/index.html#admin/users/1023929
```

Is this possible? I really hope someone can help. I need to include the index.html and add the route without changing the current directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858471/angular-2-how-to-pass-url-parameters?

Comment: I understand URL parameters but this is in regards to the way Angular actually routes based on sub-directories rather than passing parameters to the router to be digested in a component/service.